# studying the sequence $u_{n+1}=\frac{u_n}{2} -2n+4 $

Tags: sequences-and-series

let the seqeunce defined as follow
$u_{n+1}=\frac{u_n}{2} -2n+4 $ and $u_0=4$

calculate $u_{20}$

i think that i should find a closed form for the sequence because we want to calculate without a calculator

can you please help me for a way to find closed form for this sequence

Comment: You'd have to show what you tried. Generating functions, characteristic polynomials or, perhaps, simple induction?

Comment: i have calculated some terms but i could'nt see the patern, others methods (Generating functions, characteristic polynomials ) aren't familiar to me

Comment: Hint : $x_{n} = u_n + (4n-16)$

Comment: @NN2 how do find $x_n$ such that it is geometric sequence can you tell us on how you do it please

Comment: I guessed the form  $x_n = u_n +(an +b)$ and find $(a,b) = (4,-16)$

Comment: To just compute by hand is only 20 divides by 2 and 40 add/subtract operations.  That doesn't seem so hard.  There may be an easier way, but that is an upper bound.  If I were given the problem I would just start computing.  If asked for term 200 I would think about a general term, but not for 20.  I would bet that none of the divides by 2 leave a remainder

Answer (score 1):

I didn't find it so easy either, I'm not surprised you needed help.
$$\begin{aligned}
u_{n+1}&=\frac{1}{2}u_n -2(n-2),\quad
u_n=\frac 1 2u_{n-1}-2(n-3)\\
&=\frac 1 2\left[\frac 1 2u_{n-1}-2(n-3)\right]-2(n-2)\\
&=\frac 1 4 u_{n-1}-2\left(\frac{n-3}2+n-2\right), \quad u_{n-1}=\frac 1 2 u_{n-2}-2(n-4)\\
&=\frac 1 4\left[\frac 1 2 u_{n-2}-2(n-4)\right]-2\left(\frac{n-3}2+n-2\right)\\
&=\frac 1 8 u_{n-2}-\left(\frac{n-4}4+\frac{n-3}2+\frac{n-2}1\right)\\
&\vdots \\
&\vdots \quad \text{after}\quad k\quad \text{back substitution steps}\\
&\vdots\\
&=\frac 1 {2^{k+1}} u_{n-k}-\sum_{i=0}^{k}\frac{n-2-i}{2^i}\quad \text{verify with math induction, evaluate sum $S$ such that}\\
&=\left(\frac 1 {2}\right)^{k+1}u_{n-k}-S
\end{aligned}$$
Side bar to find out what S is (pre-requisite knowledge needed):
$$S
=\sum_{i=0}^k\frac{n-2-i}{2^i}
=(n-2)\sum_{i=0}^k \frac 1 {2^i}-\sum_{i=1}^k\frac{i}{2^i}\\
=(n-2)\cdot \left[2-\left(\frac 1 2\right)^k\right]-\left[k\cdot\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{k}-\left(k+1\right)\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{k-1}+2\right]\\
=2n-4-2-(n+k-2)\left(\frac 1 2\right)^k-(k+1)\left(\frac 1 2\right)^{k-1}\\
=2n-6-(n+k)\left(\frac 1 2\right)^{k}-k\left(\frac 1 2\right)^{k-1}$$
Side bar complete, picking up where we left off:
$$\begin{aligned}
u_{n+1}&=\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{k+1}u_{n-k}-\left[2n-6-(n+k)\left(\frac 1 2\right)^{k}-k\left(\frac 1 2\right)^{k-1}\right],\quad \text{this is after k back subs}\\
&\text{so after k=n of these steps:}\\
&=\left(\frac 1 {2}\right)^{n+1}u_0-2n+6+n\left(\frac 1 2\right)^{n-2},\quad u_0=\left(\frac 1 2\right)^{-2}\\
&=\left(\frac 1 2\right)^{n-1}+n\left(\frac 1 2\right)^{n-2}-2n+6\\
&=6-2n+(2n+1)\left(\frac 1 2\right)^{n-1}\\
u_n&=6-2(n-1)+(2n-1)\left(\frac 1 2\right)^{n-2}\\
&=8-2n+(2n-1)\left(\frac 1 2\right)^{n-2}\\
u_{20}&=\frac {39} {2^{18}}-32
\end{aligned}$$
Almost think it would have been easier to just directly calculate $u_{20}$.  Your teacher was likely getting at how after a certain earlier point:  $\quad u_n \approx 8-2n$

Pre-requisite knowledge I needed:  math induction geometric sums, power-geometric sums. You may have more experience with geo sums than power-geo sums.  This is a first order power geometric sum derivation:
$$\begin{aligned}
S&=\sum_{i=1}^nia^i\\
&=1\cdot a+2\cdot a^2+3\cdot a^3+\cdots+n\cdot a^n\\
S-aS&=a+(2-1)a^2+(3-2)a^3+\cdots+(n-(n-1))a^n-n\cdot a^{n+1}\\
&=a+a^2+a^3+\cdots+a^n-n\cdot a^{n+1}\\
&=-1+\frac{a^{n+1}-1}{a-1}-n\cdot a^{n+1}\\
&=\frac{a^{n+1}-1-(a-1)-n(a-1)a^{n+1}}{a-1}\\
&=\frac{a^{n+1}-a-n(a^{n+2}-a^{n+1})}{a-1}\\
&=\frac{(n+1)a^{n+1}-na^{n+2}-a}{a-1}\\
S&=\frac{na^{n+2}-(n+1)a^{n+1}+a}{(1-a)^2}
\end{aligned}$$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**
$$u_{n+1}=\frac{u_n}{2} -2n+4$$
$$u_n=v_n-4n \quad \implies  \quad v_{n+1}=\frac{v_n}{2}-8$$
$$v_n=t_n-16\quad \implies  \quad t_{n+1}=\frac{t_n}{2}$$